# make R and voodoopad interact

Tags: r, macos, applescript

I am making an intensive use of voodoopad and R. I would like to program the following functionality for voodoopad: 
If I select some text in voodoopad and type (let say) Cmd-R, the selected text is evaluated into an R session previously launched in a terminal session.

I have good programming and scripting skills but no knowledge on system programming. If somebody can give me some hints about how to achieve this project or even simply on the feasibility of this functionnality into a reasonable time, I will enjoy it.

Update:

Here is an applescript to run a given command "CommandLine" to the R session

```
set CommandLine to "plot(density(rnorm(10000)))"
try
tell application "R"
    activate
    with timeout of 90000 seconds
        cmd CommandLine
    end timeout
end tell
```

end try

So I guess that what I need now is to be able to pass a string from voodoopad to an applescript and to execute it. Is anybody know how to do that?

Comment: This is an interesting question and I might be able to give you a quick example, if I had R installed on my Mac, which I don't. In Voodoopad, you can easily link a shortcut to a script. I think you figured that out already. Do you have any example whatsoever of what you already tried to script R in AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  tell application "Voodoopad"
    set commandLine to (current selection of window 1) as text
    if commandLine is not "" then
      tell application "R"
          activate
          with timeout of 90000 seconds
              cmd CommandLine
          end timeout
      end tell
    else
      display dialog "Select a command first."
    end if
  end tell
```

It is also possible to set the commandLine to a complete page.

```
  tell application "Voodoopad"
    tell document 1
      set commandLine to text of page 1
      if commandLine is not "" then
        tell application "R"
            activate
            with timeout of 90000 seconds
                cmd CommandLine
            end timeout
        end tell
      else
        display dialog "Select a command first."
      end if
    end tell
  end tell
```

Obviously, the selected text in the first case or page 1 of document 1 in the second case needs to contain a valid command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to run the first script into the applescript editor but it gives me something like: "synthax error: « , » expected but property found". Any idea?

Comment: The error message is in french so I am not sure it will help you.

Comment: Anything is better than nothing.

Comment: "Erreur de syntaxe
 « , » prévu mais propriété trouvé."

Comment: I have added another tell block to the code in my answer. I'm not sure what the correct name of "Voodoopad" should be. You may need to use a different app name. Hopefully this is enough.